# How to make my device's IP address accessible from anywhere?

Tags: java, android, ip-address, portforwarding

I am working on an app that sends messages to other phones. Kind of like a chat messenger in a way.
The way my app is supposed to work is the user enters an IP address and a message and the app send the message to the specified IP address.
I currently have the server and client working within the same app. This way, any phone is able to connect to any other phone because each have their independent server which is accessed via the device's IP address. However, I am not able to connect to an IP address that is not located on my LAN. **I want to know how could I make the server receive messages from devices not connected to my LAN?**

I read about port forwarding and it seems like a good solution, but the security risks are not encouraging. I was also thinking about using a public IP address, such as Amazon's Web Server, to run my server on and the IP address would be accessible from anywhere world wide. The only problem with this is how would the server know which device to send the message to?

Comment: if the ip-addresses from the clients are dynamic, this can be difficult to impossible to achieve. If your server has a static ip-address, you could turn it around and have the clients frequently contact the server to see if there are messages waiting for them.

Comment: If you want someone to find you inside your LAN, you will have to expose some kind of contact information and set up routing, NAT and any other security/network measures you have in place to let them through, no way around it.

Comment: So, is port forwarding my only option or would that not even be possible on Android?

Answer (score 1):

Your "Service" that is listening for incoming messages would need a public
addressable IP address. Address in the range listed below
are referred to as private and cannot be reached "globally". They are private to your local area network.

192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 (65,536 IP addresses)
172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 (1,048,576 IP addresses)
10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 (16,777,216 IP addresses)

Further more your "service" ip address can be behind a NAT firewall,
which means that your "service" ip address that appears to be public
is not really public. NAT is where the IP gets translated to another IP address.
This typically happens at the internet service provider or telco network operator.

They way to solve this puzzle is to have a public addressable server
somewhere from some hosting company and use it to route your messages.

Each mobile client can connect to this server and obtain an identifier, possibly tied to the users email address. Once registerd the mobile client can ask the server to enqueue some messages for that particular user.

One could also use Google Cloud messaging as the delivery mechanism, this way
one could wake the mobile clients to collect a message from the server.
Or the message can even be within the push message.